# Winwheel.js + Ionic 2 (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I would like to use the Winwheel.js library inside an Ionic 2 project.
Can anyone explain the best way to integrate the library into an angular 2 component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow Ionic2 doc for adding third party libraries , the instructions are pretty clear, hope this help you

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/